# How to use WHEN for an expressions in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I see this snippet in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html

```
when (x) {
    parseInt(s) -> print("s encodes x")
    else -> print("s does not encode x")
}
```

I'm confuse wonder is the first case is `x.parseInt(s)` or something else.

The reason I ask is because, I tried the following

```
when(myString)) {
    isNullOrBlank() -> removeValue()
    else -> setValue(myString)
}
```

It fails in `isNullOrBlack()`.

I tried the following also fails.

```
when(myString)) {
    it.isNullOrBlank() -> removeValue()
    else -> setValue(it)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first case is checking if `x` is equal to the result of calling `parseInt(x)`, which is not a function of `x`.

Any case that evaluates as an expression is checked for equality with `x`. There is no way to create a case where you call a function on the target of the when statement and it passes if it returns true. Your only options when working with a target are to check its equality, check whether it is `in` something, or check whether it `is` something.

To do what you’re attempting, you need a when statement with no target.

```
when {
    myString.isNullOrBlank() -> removeValue()
    else -> setValue(myString)
}
```